# How to stop apache from treating a url ending with a slash as a directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have the following as my htaccess rules for my static files which works fine.

`http://mywebsite.local/en/testing-page` gets page from `cached_pages/en/testing-page.html`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached_pages/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html -s
RewriteRule .* cached_pages/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html [L]
```

My server also writes the index file as cached_pages/en.html which is correct. However, what htaccess RewriteCond and RewriteRule lines are needed to point to the file, so `http://mywebsite.local/en/` gets page from `cached_pages/en.html`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
???????????
???????????
```

**Please note** the URL has a **/** at the end, so it's not as straight forward as I thought.

So, how do I get the rewriterules working for the url ending with a slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to just duplicate your existing rule with an appended slash `/` and anchor it with `^` and `$`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached_pages/$1\.html -s
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ cached_pages/$1\.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached_pages/$1\.html -s
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ cached_pages/$1\.html [L]
```